# SQL - Multiple select filter: Combine filter conditions to get proper results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a filter where the user can choose different conditions for the end output. Right now I'm doing the construction of the SQL query, but whenever more conditions are selected, it doesn't work.

Example of the **advalues** table.

```
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| id | listingId | value         | identifier |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| 1  | 1a        | Alaskan Husky | race       |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| 2  | 1a        | Højt          | activity   |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| 3  | 1c        | Akita         | race       |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| 4  | 1c        | Mellem        | activity   |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
```

As you can see, there's a different row for each advalue.

**The outcome I expect**

Let's say the user has checked/ticked the checkbox for the race where it says "Alaskan Husky", then it should return the **listingId** for the match (once). If the user has selected both "Alaskan Husky" and activity level to "Low" then it should return nothing, if the activity level is either "Mellem" or "Højt" (medium, high), then it should return the listingId for where the race is "Alaskan Husky" only, not "Akita". I hope you understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

I tried something like this, which returns nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM advalues WHERE (identifier="activity" AND value IN("Mellem","Højt")) AND (identifier="race" AND value IN("Alaskan Husky"))
```

By the way, I want to select distinct listingId as well, so it only returns unique listingId's.

I will continue to search around for solutions, which I've been doing for the past few hours, but wanted to post here too, since I haven't been able to find anything that helped me yet. Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You are asking for identifier = "activity" AND identifier = "race". That will always return no results.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language (and your query are invalid standard SQL), not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @jarlh It's SQL server.

Comment: Read your sql again, and think if it's possible to get any result at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can  split the restictions on *identifier* in two tables for each type. Then you join on listingid to obtain the listingId wich have the two type of identifier.

```
SELECT ad.listingId
FROM   advalues ad
JOIN   advalues ad2
  ON ad.listingId = ad2.listingId
WHERE ( ad.identifier  = 'activity' AND ad.value  IN( 'Mellem', 'Højt' ) )
 AND  ( ad2.identifier = 'race'     AND ad2.value IN( 'Alaskan Husky' ) )
```

Comment: The thing is just if I change the activity values to "Lavt" (low) then it will still get the rows where race matches "Alaskan Husky", and "Akita" too. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: My query didn't return rows where the race is Akita. It returns a row where the listingId is 1C, wich correspond to the criteria Mellem/activity. You should consider add more sample data and desired output in table format in your question.

Comment: When you run the query you posted, and you have the same columns/rows that I showed in the example in the top post. How many rows do you get in your output? I get 3. Also for the listingId "1c" where activity is "Mellem". The "1c" listing has the race "Akita", which shouldn't be in the result, but I can see why it ends up there.. But do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Thanks Kobi, I'll do some more fiddling around later, to see how it will work with some other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't exactly clear, but I think you want this:

```
WHERE (identifier="activity" AND value IN("Mellem","Højt")) OR (identifier="race" AND value IN("Alaskan Husky"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though it's the same as @Akaino's suggestion as well. As I mentioned to him, this query also returns columns where race is other than "Alaskan Husky" but matches the activity. Both conditions needs to match.

Comment: Might just be the structure that's not suitable for this though, I'll need to go into the thinking tank later :D Just got a vaccine shot earlier and blood sample taken, so I'm not 100% right now lol

Comment: That's why your question isn't clear.   Neither is your comment.   You say "returns columns" but I think you probably mean "rows".   If you gave us a sufficient data sample and desired results, we might be able to help.

Comment: yeah sorry, I meant rows. I'll update the answer shortly with more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you are trying to fetch data with different "filters".

Your Query

```
SELECT listingId FROM advalues 
    WHERE identifier="activity" 
    AND value IN("Mellem","Højt") 
    AND identifier="race" 
    AND value IN("Alaskan Husky")
```

Will always return 0 results as you are asking for `identifier = "activity" AND identifier = "race"`

I think you wanted to do something like this instead:

```
SELECT listingId FROM advalues 
    WHERE 
    (identifier="activity" AND value IN("Mellem","Højt"))
    OR 
    (identifier="race" AND value IN("Alaskan Husky"))
```

Comment: You're right, I tried something like that as well before I posted, but let me try it again. Edit: I used "AND" instead of "OR" which is why it returned nothing.

Comment: Edit 2: But it seems this query still doesn't return the output i expect. This query also returns other advalues where race is different from "Alaskan Husky".

Comment: This query can only return values where either of those two statements is true. There can be no "race" sets where value is not "Alaskan Husky". Try copying the entire query I posted and try again. It should provide you with the IDs for all entries where `identifier="activity AND value in ("Mellem", "Hojt")` PLUS the IDs for all entries where `identifier="race" AND value in ("Alaskan Husky")`. Don't use the query without all the parantheses.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the fact that it's multiple rows. For example, the identifier with "race" is one row in the "advalues" table, and the "activity" is another. What do you think?